# UICollectionView - when/how to get sizes of views within Cell, using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView`. Its cells are prototyped in a Storyboard, and each cell has a hierarchy of views configured with Auto Layout.

I am implementing the following `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol method:

```
collectionView(_ layout:sizeForItemAt)
```

**Requirement**: I need the final bounds of views within the cell, so that I can configure the contents of the cell. (The bounds are used in the creation of pixel-exact images with are then fed to the cells.) Please note that I can't calculate the bounds manually in `sizeForItemAt`, due to a complex hierarchy and Auto Layout: it would be too fragile.)

**Problem**:  when `collectionView(_ collectionView:, cellForItemAt)` is called, final layout has not yet occurred. The various cell bounds are still the values set in the Storyboard.

Same thing for `collectionView(_ collectionView:, willDisplay:, forItemAt:)`

Same thing for `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

**Question**: how do I get accurate, final cell geometry information, before the cells are rendered? Cheers.

Comment: Is [this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637424/change-uicollectionview-cell-size-depending-on-label-size) useful to you?

Comment: @AhmadF Awesome. That did the trick, thank you! How do I accept your comment as the correct Answer? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AhmadF for the link to the answer. (See responses to question.)

Solution: tell the cell to layout before doing the calcs:

```
// ... De-queue cell here.

cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()

// ... Perform geometry calcs here.
```